# App or site to make font-based clipart?

Tags: image-processing, vector-graphics

I want to make a set of images of letters and numbers, in different colors.  Specifically I'm working on a children's game, and want a 100x100 px image of each alphabet (English) letter and number.  Ideally, I'd like variations of each image in a few colors, too.

I know I can manually create each one in GIMP, or maybe even script something out (not fully sure on how that would work yet), but is there something out there that would already generate what I want or more easily help me do the work?

edit: To clarify, I think I'm looking for .png images as the final output.  Web-based or GUI or CLI, it doesn't matter.  I'm running Linux, but have access to Windows machines; I guess if it's OSX only then it's out.

For instance, if I'm walking through doing it manually, I'm going to take GIMP and create a new 100x100 image, then place a block letter "A" in the image and fill it with a color blue.  Then I'll export to something like "a_blue.png".  And then repeat, "b_blue.png", "c_blue.png", etc.  I'm looking for anything that might make this process easier.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need a bit more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically for this question I'd suggest answering: what OS(es)? does it have to be Vector or Bitmap? CLI or GUI?

Comment: That would be fairly easy to code in PHP using GD2. Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ColoredLetterGenerator

https://github.com/ComFreek/ColoredLetterGenerator
Disclaimer: I am the author of the project.

#### Features

- PHP cli
- Loading configuration data from a JSON file (well, it's not quite a feature, this is the only way to use the software)

#### How to use

1. Start a command line and run `cli.php`.
2. Choose your configuration file. There two files already provided in the `samples` directory.
3. Type an arbitrary name for the output directory.

See the GitHub project site for more information.

#### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've finally implemented multiple background colors. Unfortunately, this is a breaking change, so you have to add the "backgroundColors" block to your configuration files (see the project site for more information).

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you want something like a bitmap font generator. There's hundreds out there, below are a few popular ones:

- http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/
- http://www.lmnopc.com/bitmapfontbuilder/
- (Online) http://kvazars.com/littera/

Most also let you customize the font in some way to give it effects before exporting.

Regarding exporting to separate images, I recommend using the spritesheet that most of these export as it is easier to work with (inside your game) and is smaller size-wise than a bunch of individual files.

Comment: Thanks!  My goal actually is to assemble everything into a spritesheet; The tutorial I'm following points to another app that assembles collections of images into one.  I didn't realize some of these already would take care of that for you, will check them out!